# Uploading file using file parameter Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm trying to upload a file through a pipeline using a file parameter, but every time I try to view the content of the file, it tells me it's null, so I suspect it's not being passed correctly from my machine.

This is my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        file(name: 'archivo', description: 'Adjunta un archivo')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage ('Importar archivo') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //sh "cp ${params.archivo} ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                    def archivo = "${env.WORKSPACE}/${params.archivo}"
                    if (fileExists(archivo)) {
                        def contenido = readFile archivo
                        echo contenido
                    } else {
                        echo "No existe: ${archivo}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Importar archivo)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
No existe: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline/null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I've been trying to copy the file into the workspace in case it wasn't located properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your logs are inconsistent with your code.

Comment: Updated logs, I mistakenly passed the wrong one. My bad.

Comment: params.archivo returns null, check if you really need "file"  or can change to "string" or use https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/#plugin-content-usage-in-declarative-pipeline